# How to execute code before TestNG for ie. building up the test suite

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, ota, test-suite

i am using Selenium2 + TestNG + Maven2 + alot of other stuff.
What I would like to do is to build the testng.xml (xml suite) on-the-fly upon
test execution, because I would read those tests out of HP ALM QC via OpenTestArchitecture (OTA).
Is there anyway to tell maven and surefire to NOT start TestNG immediately, instead to
call a main method somewhere, where I could build my test suite via

```
XmlSuite xs = new XmlSuite();
XmlTest xt = new XmlTest(xs);
...
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
tng.run();
```

the purpose is also to capture all types of exceptions to be able to write back the
results from TestNG into HP ALM QC via OTA. Recently I had a exception from String.format and it killed my whole script because it happened in my TestNG @AfterMethod

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to make things in the pre-integration-test life-cycle-phase and prepare there the testng.xml afterwards you can run the integration tests. The complete thing can be done via

```
mvn verify
```

You can start with a simple proof of concept.

Comment: uff, i googled a bit and could not figure it out, you have any hint, i checked the Maven book, but if you have no clue (like i do), its seems tricky :/